# In Python Boto's API for DynamoDB, what are the differences between Layer1 and Layer2?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

Which should be used and for what? 
Is there any advantage to one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only a matter of abstraction levels. In most cases, you will want to use the highest level API.

- **Layer1** API is a direct mapping of Amazon's API
- **layer2** API add some nice abstractions like a generator for `scan` and `query` results as well as answer cleaning.

When you call layer2, it calls layer1 which ends up generating HTTP calls.

Comment: Where is layer1 documented?